# Pyinstaller converted exe files not running on windows 7

Tags: python

I created a python script which opens some tabs and some programs and in a directory creates a folder. Now the problem is when using pyinstaller i converted this .py file into .exe file it was succesfully converted but when i ran this .exe file in virtual machine windows 7 it gives an error 
The program can't start because api-ms-wncrt-runtime-I1-1-0.dll is missing.

Is there a way to include all such modules inside the .py file so that the program runs somehow

**UPDATED**

i used pyinstaller -w -F .py. Now i copied the exe file 
only into the shared folder cuz i only want the exe file .

Following are the modules i imported in my python code

import tkinter
import input1
import input2
import random
import webbrowser as wb
from tkinter import *
import subprocess
import os    So is there a way to include any library or module which will solve this issue

Comment: Hello, have you solved this issue after almost 2 years?

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the -F option when using pyinstaller?

When you do:

```sh
pyinstaller -F python_file.py
```

It grabs all of the modules you've used to make the package (provided you have them in your envrionment I think) and makes it into one file.  If it makes a separate folder for the libraries, you have to copy the folder around with the exe file or it won't work.

If this ms-wncrt-runtime is not a python module then afaik you can't add this to your python package and will need to install it on your machine separately.  Hope that helps.

Comment: i used pyinstaller -w -F <script>.py. Now i copied the exe file only into the shared folder cuz i only want the exe file .Following are the modules i imported in my python code

Comment: import tkinter
import input1
import input2
import random
import webbrowser as wb
from tkinter import *
import subprocess
import os    So is there a way to include any library or module which will solve this issue